# How to install Teamviz in Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I need to know how to install [Teamviz Pomodoro](http://www.teamviz.com/pomodoro-app/) in Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the next packages. For installing use the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_NAME.deb
```

1. Download and install these packages

   - [`libgcrypt11`](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/multiarch-support_2.19-0ubuntu6.9_amd64.deb)
   - [`libgnutls26`](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnutls26/libgnutls26_2.12.23-12ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb)
   - [`libtasn1-3`](http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/libt/libtasn1-3/libtasn1-3_2.13-2+deb7u3_amd64.deb)
2. Download and install the latest version of Teamviz Pomodoro from http://www.teamviz.com/downloads/

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to run `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libxss1 ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: Probably, but how do you know these packages match with the others?

Comment: it's what the site says to install. I copied the command and just added the restricted extras, which was recommended to fix audio problems. Do you know where that site is based, by the way? It took about 5 minutes to load from the Northeast USA.

Comment: @Zacharee1: It loads fine for me though the host has a round trip time of 150–200 ms (central Europe).

Comment: @DavidFoerster yeah. I just tried again and it loaded fine. It must have been my weird router.

Comment: Have you tried to install Teamviz in Ubuntu 16.04? I would swear that I was unable to install it with that commands

Comment: It throws error: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory    So I was right

Comment: I just tried to install it on Kubuntu 16.04 and it has more unsatisfied dependencies. Also I think they do not offer support anymore

Comment: I retracted my original down-vote, but IMHO the answer still needs work to deserve an up-vote: 1) `libgcrypt11` links to an entirely different `.deb` file, 2) the packages come from different distributions and 3) at the moment I cannot verify which shared libraries are actually required by TeamViz because their download link is broken.

Comment: Now it is available again for downloading. I appreciate your retract.

Comment: Package `libtasn1-3` doesn't exist in 16.04. And it works without it in 16.04

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:*** Counter to my original assessment these instructions only work in Precise (12.04) and Trusty (14.04).

1. Install library dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libxss1
   ```

   For audio codecs you may also need:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
   ```
2. Download the TeamViz installer archive for your architecture from http://www.teamviz.com/downloads/ and extract it.
3. Run the installer executable `TeamViz/TeamViz` from the extracted archive.

   If you want a system-wide installation, open a terminal, navigate to the extracted directory and run:

   ```
   gksudo ./TeamViz
   ```

Comment: Can someone verify that this solution is working? If not try the next one, that worked for me

Comment: It throws `error: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Odd. The installation instructions don't mention that. You can always find and install the [package providing that file](/q/481/175814) (in this case `libgcrypt11`).

Comment: I installed apt-file but it does not find nothing with the command `apt-file find libgcrypt.so.11`. For the moment my solution is the only one valid and has negative comment :/

Comment: @LorenzoLerate Why didn't this work for you? You don't need `apt-file` to find libgcrypt. Use `dpkg -L libgcrypt11` you'll see

Comment: My mistake, the `libgcrypt11` package was replaced by a more recent version in Xenial, so there's no `libcrypt.so.11` either: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgcrypt.so.11&mode=&suite=xenial&arch=amd64.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the requisite dependencies:

sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libxss1

2. Download and install these two debian pakcages:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/libgnutls26/download
https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/libgcrypt11/download

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgnutls26_2.12.23-12ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb
```

3. Download TeamViz itself and uncompress TeamViz:

tar -xvf TeamViz.3.2.x64.tar.gz

4. Run TeamViz:

./TeamViz/TeamViz